# google script authentication error when accessing google drive and email

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script

After reviewing the beginners videos and reviewing some google script code templates, I started creating my own google script inside one of my spreadsheets. I am having trouble with authentication.  I get error after error from the script engine that it cannot access my drive or email.  When I run the script, I press the allow button on the window that prompts for access to my drive and email.  I have tried several scripts with the same result.  Is there something that I am missing?  Possibly some global account setting?

Here is a link to a pdf that has screenshots of the code with error, screenshot of my drive, and screen shot of my account settings for that particular project.

[View PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B53Qylni6FXEdWs0VXFDdGZ1bGc/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks.

Chris